# Align the Bootstrap Datetimepicker so that it rests above the textbox instead of below

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

How do you align the [Bootstrap Datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) so that it rests above the textbox instead of below. My popup window is currently being cut out by another div.

[image]

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datetime').datetimepicker({
        locale: 'en'
    });
});
<input type="text" class="form-control booking" id="datetime" placeholder="I want it now">
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/HJHq8/201/)

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle example ?

Comment: What do you mean by "rests above the textbox"?

Comment: I want to be able to adjust the position of the datetimepicker modal that pops up when the user clicks on the textbox. Instead of it being positioned below the textbox, I want it to be positioned above - http://jsfiddle.net/HJHq8/201/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `widgetPositioning` option did the trick:

```
$('#datetime').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'en',
    widgetPositioning: {
        vertical: 'top',
        horizontal: 'left'
    }
});
```